# Is there a proof that $\pi \times e$ is irrational?

Tags: number-theory, pi, irrational-numbers

A little reading suggests:

It is known that either $\pi + e$ or $\pi \times e$ is transcendental (or possibly both), but no proof is known that one of those two numbers in particular is transcendental.

If we just want irrationality rather than transcendence, is a proof known?

Can we prove $\pi+e$ is irrational?  Can we prove $\pi \times e$ is irrational?

Comment: See this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40145/irrationality-of-pie-pipi-and-epi2

Comment: And this: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51617.html

Comment: See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08394.pdf) it’s been recently proven that it’s irrational. @NebulousReveal

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is not known whether $\pi + e$ is irrational, nor whether $\pi \times e$ is irrational. See $\# 22$ [here](http://www.math.ou.edu/~jalbert/courses/openprob2.pdf).

Comment: I typeset your answer to change * to $\times$ and to add the webpage as a link. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Sivaram: Not at all, thanks for cleaning it up.

Comment: The link does not work anymore. [Here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=1h1YKOImdD9cB3_r26W2h6JMcoubjt1v15HhMTVapZkrBDhUUH_nqO6gpaNsY) is the version from Google cache.