# Why is it hard to prove whether $\pi+e$ is an irrational number?

Tags: soft-question, exponential-function, pi, transcendental-numbers, rationality-testing

From [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics#Analysis) I came to know that it is hard to conclude $\pi+e$ is an irrational? Can somebody discuss with reference "Why this is hard ?"

Is it still an open problem ? If yes it will be helpful to any student what kind ideas already used but ultimately failed to conclude this.

Comment: According to mathworld, it's still an open problem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/e.html

Comment: The same think is asked in (a part of) this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28243/is-there-a-proof-that-pi-times-e-is-irrational

Comment: I don't think this is precisely a duplicate of the other question, as this one asks for references and discussion about why previous techniques are insufficient to resolve the problem. (I've edited the title to match.) This can be more illuminating than a simple yes/no answer, which is what the previous question received.

Comment: After Rahul Narain's [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/159350/revisions) the title of the question corresponds to the body. So it seems that it is a different question - I apologize for being too quick in voting to close.

Comment: I think the expectation is that much more is true: $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraically independent. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33817/work-on-independence-of-pi-and-e.

Comment: If it were rational, it would be difficult

Comment: It is easy to see that both the sum and the product of two transcendentals can be rational or even integer. But proving that the sum or product of two given transcendentals is rational is an open problem, particularly for the two more famous transcendents $e$ and $\pi$.

Answer (score 116):

"Why is this hard?" I think a different question would be "Why would it be easy?"

But there are some things that are known. It is known that $\pi$ and $e$ are transcendental. Thus $(x-\pi)(x-e) = x^2 - (e + \pi)x + e\pi$ cannot have rational coefficients. So at least one of $e + \pi$ and $e\pi$ is irrational. It's also known that at least one of $e \pi$ and $e^{\pi^2}$ is irrational (see, e.g., this [post at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40145/irrationality-of-pie-pipi-and-epi2)).

Comment: Do most mathematicians think it is irrational, or is it viewed as 50/50?

Comment: @Ovi mathematicians don't work like that. They either say, with certainty, "based on our axiom system, X IS", and then it'd be 100/0, or they say "based on our axiom system, X is UNDECIDABLE", or they say "maybe there's a proof for X, but it hasn't been found, so this is something I make NO STATEMENT on". Math is not done via polls, and when working mathematically, you *abhor* the idea of saying "I believe that X is". Either you can prove X, or you cannot make any statement based on a's veracity. You can, of course, take X as a *hypothesis* and build complex things on it, but then you'd …

Comment: … **always** remember X is just a hypothesis. Otherwise, you'd be a sloppy mathematician, and that is a *bad* mathematician. Notice that a lot of mathematicians are still social people and you can try to persuade them to pick either X or NOT X in a poll if you don't offer the  "NOT YET PROVEN" option, but using the result of that poll would be equivalent to asking healthy people whether they'd rather be struck with either AIDS or cancer, getting e.g. a 70/30 result and then claiming that 70% of people would like to have cancer.

Comment: @Ovi I think most people think it's irrational, i.e. they'd be VERY surprised if it turns out to be rational.

Comment: Is it strange that I agree with Marcus's comments *and also* agree with @AkivaWeinberger's comment?

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's not true at all. Subjective probability guides mathematicians' efforts all the time, to focus them on where they think they're most likely to bear fruit. For instance, most mathematicians believe the Riemann hypothesis is true. That doesn't mean they *know* it's true, just that they think it's more likely to be true than false (in the form of betting odds, if you want). For a formalization of this idea, see [logical induction](https://intelligence.org/files/LogicalInduction.pdf).

Comment: @user76284 exactly my point! So, if you're proving something, and your proof requires the Riemann Hypothesis to be true, you'd very clearly note that. You're not actually contradicting me...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Of course. What I mean is, mathematicians have internal beliefs (reflected as odds or probabilities) about the truth of statements, even before those statements have been proven or disproven. Otherwise, arguably, mathematics would be completely intractable (just a brute-force enumeration of proofs).

Comment: @user76284 or were you referring to my use of the word "abhor"? That might have been a bit strong, but again, I find it a very natural thing (and I see that in any mathematical work) to apply Occam's Razor, i.e. to keep one's axiom system as small as possible in any way – up to a point where working on a hypothesis has the undeniable advantage of letting you continue your work :)

Comment: ah simultaneous commenting, @user76284 :) yes, I think I fully agree with you.

Comment: Wait. All you needed was the transcendantality of pi and e. So does that mean for any pair of transcendental numbers p and q, pq or p+q must be irrational?

Answer (score 18):

I was actually going to ask the same question... and in particular if the result would follow as the consequence of any hard, still open conjecture. From the [MO thread mentioned by lhf](https://mathoverflow.net/a/33820/65810) (not the same as the one mentioned by mixedmath) I found out that [Schanuel's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) would imply it.

On the Mathworld page for $e$ there's a bit of info on numerical attempts to (how should I say?) verify that you cannot easily disprove the irrationality:

> It is known that $\pi+e$ and $\pi/e$ do not satisfy any polynomial equation of degree $\leq 8$ with integer coefficients of average size $10^9$.

Obtaining this [result in 1988](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-50-181/S0025-5718-1988-0917835-1/S0025-5718-1988-0917835-1.pdf) required the use of a Cray-2 supercomputer (at NASA Ames Research Center). I guess one could add that the Ferguson–Forcade algorithm, which was used in this computation, [gets a bit of flak on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm). In fact, the author of this paper, D.H. Bailey, later co-developed the superior PSLQ algorithm. So it is interesting that the problem has advanced computational science too, in a way.

Comment: Numerical attempts were done for fun I assume. Otherwise it is obviously a red herring, the numbers are bound to be transcendental. It would be immensely surprising if they are not.

Comment: @KalEl
Agreed... there would be an amazing connection between e and pi for any of those numbers to be rational. However, then e^(i pi) comes to mind. Its pretty amazing that its rational.