# Any proof to $\pi^{e}$'s irrationality?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, irrational-numbers, pi, open-problem

I've searched for this for a while but get nothing...

There are plenty of proofs to irrationality of $e$,$\pi$,$e^{\pi}$. However, I can't find a proof for $\pi^e$. More, when searching for this I got a answer **Unknown** on [this site(in Chinese)](http://www.matrix67.com/blog/archives/3718), which says

> 目前为止， $\pi^e$ 是否有理还是一个谜。
>
> Whether $\pi^e$ is irrational or not is unknown up to now(2010).

Thus, I just wanna know whether there's progressing these years...

Comment: How do you know that's irrational. You *do not* know.(Until its proved).

Comment: Sorry for that but I misunderstood a wrong proof... which is from a collection of that kind of stuff...

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159350/why-is-it-hard-to-prove-whether-pie-is-an-irrational-number

Answer (score 4):

In the sixth edition of *'An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers'* by Hardy and Wright (revised by Heath-Brown and Silverman) published in 2008, in section 4.2 they state that for $\pi^e$ this is still open. Other numbers whose irrationality has not been proved include $2^e, \pi^{\sqrt{2}}, e+\pi$.

Thus, as of 2008, this was not yet resoled.