# Can we take an $i$th root?

Tags: complex-analysis, irrational-numbers

I misread [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385704/any-proof-to-pies-irrationality) and began thinking about the value $e^\pi$. This lead me to the Wikipedia on [Gelfond's Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant), which suggests deriving a numerical value for $e^{\pi}$ by using Euler's identity:
$$e^{i\pi}=-1\\
\sqrt[i]{e^{i\pi}}=\sqrt[i]{-1}\\ e^{\pi}=(-1)^{-i}\approx 23.14069$$

My question is, how can we go about taking an $i$th root? This just doesn't seem like something that would be well-defined. This congruence along with the numerical approximation is mind-boggling.

Comment: For real number $a$ not zero, and complex number $z$, $\sqrt[a]{z}:= \sqrt[a]{|z|}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{a}}$ is usually the the real root of a complex number. So how does that help you?

Comment: The ith root of -1, that hurts my fingers when typing it. What I do know that the "double power" rule does not hold generally when dealing with complex exponents. That's what you indicate doing when you "cancel" the i on the left hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if $y,z$ are complex numbers, we don't have a single value of $y^z$. Rather, we have to take a value of $\log y$, and compute $e^{z\log y}$. Unfortunately, there can be infinitely many values of $\log y$. If $e^w=y$ then $e^{w+i2\pi k} = y$ for all integers $k$.

Thus we can write $\log -1 = i(\pi + 2\pi k)$ and thus $(-1)^i = e^{-\pi-2\pi k}$. So the possible values for $(-1)^i$ are of the form $e^{\pi n}$ where $n$ can be any odd integer.

You can see this as an extension of the idea that there is more than one square root of $2$. In general, there are infinitely many possible values for $y^z$, but if $z$ is an integer, the different values of $\log y$ yield the same value, and if $z$ is a rational number, $y^z$ can only take finitely many values. However, the general case there are infinite possible values of $y^z$.

Comment: (When we want $\log$ to be a function by choosing a branch cut, as we usually do, then there's only one value, though.)

Comment: But then, the "standard" branch cut doesn't include a value of $-1$... @anon

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Let us consider $\sqrt[i]{1}$, if $i^2=-1$.

Obviously, one of the ($i$)th roots of $1$ is $1$.

But there can be multiple ($i$)th roots, just as $1$ has two square roots and three cube roots.

If $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm and $z$ is an integer...

$$\sqrt[i]{1}=1^{-i}=e^{i2z*(-i)}=e^{2z}$$

As we can see, the only rational value is if $z=0$, per the Gelfond-Schneider theorem. In any case, all $i$th roots of 1 are real numbers.

Let us evaluate $\sqrt[i]{-2}$

Let $H$ be the measure of a half-circle (180 degrees,  radians, 200 grads, 2 quadrants, etc.)

$$\sqrt[i]{-2}=(-2)^{-i}=e^{(ln(-2)+i2z)(-i)}=e^{(ln(2)+i(2z+1))(-i)}=e^{(-iln(2)+(2z+1))}=e^{(2z+1)}cos(\frac{-Hln(2)}{})+ie^{(2z+1)}sin(\frac{-Hln(2)}{})$$

For $z=0$, this is about $-919.0189-i$14.786$