# $\pi + e$ is rational or $\pi-e$ is rational

Tags: analysis, pi

I was asked to find the truth value of the statement:

> $$
> \pi + e \; \text{ is rational or } \pi - e\; \text{ is rational }
> $$

I am only allowed to use the fact that $\pi, e $ are irrational numbers and cannot use the theory of transcendental numbers.

Cannot proceed. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you succeed, you'll be famous. Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013533/is-it-known-if-pi-e-is-transcendental-over-the-rational-numbers

Comment: @SimonS: Guess I have a beef to pick with my teacher.

Comment: If you only know that two numbers $a$ and $b$ are irrational, and you are asked whether at least one of $a-b$ and $a+b$ is rational, the answer may be true or false depending on $a$ and $b$. Did you mean that you are actually allowed to use definitions of $\pi$ and $\mathrm e$, or only the fact that they are some irrational numbers?

Comment: I seems to me that the **OR** should be **AND** in the OP and title. The truth value is _False_ as noted by Martin Brandenburg in his answer.

Comment: @FredKline: Perhaps the exercise was given as stated and the author of that exercise confused "or" with "and"?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: It's from a past paper of an Intro to Analysis course. The exercise is as is. But I'll verify if there was a mistake in a day's time. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems to be an open problem. It is a conjecture that the statement is false, i.e. that $\pi + e$ and $\pi - e$ are irrational. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) this remains unproven. (Just imagine the impact of the discovery of an equation such as $\pi=e+\frac{4233108252.........3123782}{31238295213.......0591231}$ ... unbelievable!)

Remark that at least one of those numbers is irrational, even transcendental (but this doesn't prove that both are irrational!). For if both would be algebraic, then their sum would be algebraic, which is $2 \pi$, a contradiction. Notice that this argument is not constructive at all, and again that it does not decide if "$\pi+e$ is rational or $\pi-e$ is rational" is false or not, it only proves that the stronger statement "$\pi+e$ is rational and $\pi-e$ is rational" is false.

Answer (score 11):

$2\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt2$ are two distinct irrational numbers s.t. the statement: '$2\sqrt2+\sqrt2$ is rational or $2\sqrt2-\sqrt2$ is rational' **is not true**.

$\sqrt2$ and $2-\sqrt2$ are two distinct irrational numbers s.t. the statement: '$\sqrt2+(2-\sqrt2)$ is rational or $\sqrt2-(2-\sqrt2)$ is rational' **is true**.

This illustrates that the statement cannot be proved purely based on the fact that $\pi$ and $e$ are irrational.