# is $\frac{e}{\pi}$ irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

if $e$ and $π$ are irrational numbers, is $\frac{e}{\pi}$  irrational too?

How to prove it?

Comment: I think this is an open question (nobody knows). also, note that in general the quotient of two irrational numbers may or may not be irrational

Comment: Welcome to MSE. On a related note, you may find MathOverflow's [Irrationality of $ \pi e, \pi^{\pi}$ and $e^{\pi^2}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40145/irrationality-of-pi-e-pi-pi-and-e-pi2) interesting.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159350/why-is-it-hard-to-prove-whether-pie-is-an-irrational-number

Answer (score 6):

It is currently unknown whether $\frac{e}{\pi}$ is irrational. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number#Open_questions