# Which numbers can be expressed as $a+b\pi$, with $a$ and $b$ being integers?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

Since $a$ and $b$ are both integers, there is only a countable amount of numbers $a+b\pi$. Thus not every real number can be expressed as such.

But is there a way to determine if $x$ can be expressed as $a+b\pi$, like a fundamental property of $x$? What about if $a$ and $b$ are rational? Or if instead of $\pi$ you take another irrational number?

Comment: Regarding the second question, [nobody yet knows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159350/) whether $e + \pi$ is rational :-) (click a few links there for more context)

Comment: To give a "way to determine" if $x = a + b\pi$, requires you to specify precisely how $x$, $a$ and $b$ are represented. If (for example), they are represented as [computable reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number), then there is no way to determine any equality.

Comment: @RobArthan I meant if given a real number $x$, how can one determine if it's expressible as $a + b\pi$?

Comment: But what do you mean by "given"? How is $x$ presented to you?

Comment: @RobArthan As a variable, without any specific representation. I thought maybe there'd be a property such as that $x/\pi$ is rational or something like that.

Comment: I see. I don't think that there is any useful property that will help.

Comment: There is a 'tautological' answer: $x$ is of the form $a+b\pi$ if there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $(x-a)/b=\pi$. This is what could be called a $\Sigma_1$ definition: it asks for the existence of a pair of integers satisfying a certain condition. (This is the same as asking for a single integer satisfying a certain condition, but we won't go into that). Note that your statement '$x/\pi$ is rational' is also a $\Sigma_1$ statement: it says 'there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $x\times a=b\times\pi$'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: You haven't said so, but I'll add: when a tautological answer is also so simple, it's not at all clear to me what the question is.

Comment: @LeeMosher I've thought about when you asked this, but I wanted to know whether one can somehow link this problem to known categories such as rational, algebraic or transcendental numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowledge about this sort of problem is pretty limited. The general relevant area of mathematics is *transcendental number theory*, which has some interesting and notable results, but for most questions one can think to ask, such as whether $e$ can be a rational linear combination of $1$ and $\pi$, we simply don't know the answer.

A set $A$ of numbers is said to be *algebraically independent* if for any finite subset $\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\}$ of distinct elements of $S$, no nonzero polynomial $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ with rational coefficients satisfies $P(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n) = 0$. For example, $\{\pi\}$ is an algebraically independent set (equivalently, $\pi$ is a transcendental number): there is no combination of rational numbers $a_0, \ldots, a_n$ such that

$$a_n \pi^n + a_{n-1}\pi^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0 = 0$$
except for the trivial case where all the $a_i$ are zero. This would mean for instance that no nontrivial rational combination of powers $\pi^k$ with $k \geq 2$ can ever be of the form $a + b\pi$ (here and elsewhere, $a, b$ denote rational numbers).

Relatedly, no algebraic number except $0$ can ever be of the form $a + b\pi$ for rational $a, b$.

If we have a set $S$ of algebraically independent numbers that includes $\pi$, then for any nontrivial rational polynomial $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, the value of $P(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ for $\alpha_i \in S$ will never be of the form $a + b\pi$ unless all the $\alpha_i$ are equal to $\pi$ (and even there, the possibilities are extremely constrained, as we just saw).

The following sets are known to be algebraically independent:

- (Nesterenko) $\{\pi, e^\pi, \Gamma(\frac1{4})\}$, where $\Gamma$ denotes the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
- (Baker) $\{\pi, \log 2, \log 3, \log 5, \ldots, \log p, \ldots, \}$ where $p$ ranges over primes ($\log$ is the natural logarithm).

There is a raft of conjectures about algebraically independent sets. One very powerful conjecture is [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture), and there are various conjectures surrounding the concept of [period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_(algebraic_geometry)), but as I say, these are conjectural and we seem to be very far away from settling them.

Of course, all this is about numbers that *can't* be of the form $a + b\pi$. This is only to be expected; as you say yourself, there are only countably many such $a + b\pi$, a piddingly small subset among all real numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The set $ \left\{ a+b\pi, (a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}^2 \right\}$ is *dense* in $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that given any real number, you can construct a sequence of elements of this set that converges to this number . This is due to $\pi$ being irrational, which can be proved at a college level in a guided exercise.
The more general fact that $a\mathbb{Z}+b\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ iff $\frac{a}{b} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ can be proved from the density of the additive subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$, usually using the greatest lower bound property.

To answer your question about the fundamental property, I guess more detail is needed on the assumptions you can make on $x$. For other irrational numbers such as square roots, there's a whole theory known as algebraic field extensions.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's an observation (that doesn't seem very relevant) and a comment.

Comment: @RobArthan Can't say I disagree.Technically, it doesn't answer the question. However I will leave it to those more knowledgeable than I to provide a "definitive" answer. I do get why the observation might not seem relevant to you, but in my view it has the merit of providing some information about the set mentioned in the question. As a general guideline, is providing a pseudo-answer worse than no answer at all ?