# Online tool to check if number is rational or irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

I am new to this forum. I've been programing for some time, and now starting my engineering degree. I am trying to find an online utility that will help me grasp the concept of irrational numbers (summary, multiplication, devision etc.) through trial and error. I am looking for an online tool that will give me a yes no answer if a number is rational or irratioonall.

Do you know of any such tools? 
I Hope this question is in the right stackexchange site.

Comment: Although you've gotten an answer, this is not the right place for this question. Just fyi.

Comment: What format do you have those numbers in? Any irrational number will have an infinite, non-periodic decimal expansion, so there is no obvious way to store it on a computer (and no real advantage to "small" numbers).

Comment: Any number you can type in by entering a finite number of digits is always going to be rational. I guess you mean you want to enter expressions like $\sqrt{7}$, $\pi/5$, and so on, and see if they are rational. But this is a surprisingly hard problem in general: for example, [nobody knows whether $\pi + e$ is rational or irrational](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28243/856).

Comment: @RahulNarain: That would be good as an answer.

Comment: But @Henning, I don't know if it answers the question. The question asks about numbers, I was only extrapolating about arbitrary expressions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply try [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%2042%20rational?).