# Prove or Disprove: $e = m\pi + n$ for some integers $m$ and $n$.

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, open-problem

I would like to prove or disprove the following statement:

There exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $e = m\pi + n$ (where $e=2.7...$)

Edit: any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Are $\pi$ and $e$ algebraically independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456097/are-pi-and-e-algebraically-independent) (though this is much stronger statement than here)

Comment: Thanks for that! So it seems proving my statement will be elusive, but I'm still curious if anyone knows how to disprove it.

Comment: That's great that you want to take on that challenge.  Why post here with the expectation that we prove it for you?  "I want to prove this: xyz".  That's not even a question.  You want to do so, that's nice and all.  Now what's your question?

Comment: Closely related:  [Do $e$ and $\pi$ satisfy a non-trivial diophantine equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516222/do-e-and-pi-satisfy-a-non-trivial-diophantine-equation)  The argument there shows this is an open problem.

Comment: Given the strong regularity of the continued fraction of $e$ and the apparent irregularity of the continued fraction of $\pi$ it looks extremely unlikely that $(\pi\mathbb{Z}+e\mathbb{Z})\cap\mathbb{Z}\neq \{0\}$. On the other hand we don't even know the exact irrationality measure of $\pi$, so I guess this question is fated to be an open problem for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nobody knows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Possibly_transcendental_numbers) whether $e \pm \pi$ is rational. So it seems most probable that no one knows the answer to your question.